# How to retrieve the currently logged on user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, session

I have writen my own session based authentication. In Global.asax I have added this function that takes enviroment username and check if it exist in database:

```
Protected Sub Session_Start(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim userData As UserLogin = _
        New UserLogin(Convert.ToString(Environment.UserName))

    If userData.IsValid Then
        Authentication.SaveUserToSession(userData)
    End If
End Sub
```

And this is how i save userstate to session in authentication class:

```
Public Shared Sub SaveUserToSession(user As UserLogin)

    HttpContext.Current.Session("Username") = user.Username
    HttpContext.Current.Session("isValid") = user.IsValid
    HttpContext.Current.Session("isAdmin") = user.IsAdmin
    HttpContext.Current.Session("ID") = user.Id

End Sub
```

When I display in view:

```
<ul >
    <li>Welcome @HttpContext.Current.Session("Username")</li>
</ul>
```

Everyone sees the same username. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create an intranet web site that authenticates users logged into a Windows domain you can use ASP.NET Identity with Windows Authentication. You have to change authentication to **Windows Authentication**:

[image: Windows Authentication]

Normally, when you access `Environment.UserName` the get the name of the user owning the executing process and in ASP.NET this user is a service account (and not the user sending the request from a web browser). However, when you use Windows Authentication this behavior changes and you can now use `Environment.UserName` to get the name of the remote user. Obviously, this only works on an intranet with a Windows domain.

Really, you should not use `Environment.UserName` in an ASP.NET application because it changes behavior based on the authentication used. Instead you can inspect the `User` property which is available in both the controller and view in ASP.NET applications based on the newest versions of the framework and it will give you information about the remote user if he or she is logged in.

Answer (score 2):

`System.Environment.UserName` returns the identity under which the application pool that hosts your web site is running.

So in your case this is always your account.

So depending on the security method you have implemented you have to use the appropriate way to retrieve the currently logged on user name.

Comment: so how to get windows username ?

Comment: As said, that depends on the authentication method you are using (windows, forms,..). So what are you using?

Comment: i think i am using none as i have written a method that checks if current user is in database and sets session variables and before each view i check session variables

Comment: Well, first decide what authentication method you want to use.

Comment: i am almost certian i'm gonna use windows authentication - so i set authentication=Windows in web.config ?

Answer (score 1):

As per the MSDN documentation Environment.UserName "**Gets the user name of the person who is currently logged on to the Windows operating system.**".

So it's no use to you for getting the user that's logging into your website, and because you're always the user who is logged into the OS everyone will always get your data.

Comment: hmmm so should i use System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() or should i change my idea completly ?

Comment: That depends. What is your current authentication mode for the website?

Comment: authentication mode = none   because i wanted to write my own

Comment: And how do you want the users to log in, do you want it to automatically pass in their Windows credentials or to log into a form?

Comment: automatically connect without writting credentials

Comment: OK, so you want to set up your web config with authentication mode="Windows" then I think HttpContext.User should give you the details.

Comment: it stills return nothing ;/

Comment: Actually nothing? Empty string or null, or just not what you expect?